# When do nouns convert between mass and count?

Tags: grammatical-number, nouns, email, uncountable-nouns

I confess to having the pedantic hangup of refusing to use `email` as a count noun, but it's a lost cause.

Over the past week I've been working on a modeling and simulation proposal, and I've noticed that the M&S community seems to find `code` as a count noun to be acceptable usage, *e.g.*,

> Conservative codes adopt the approach of …

What are the rules that make conversions from mass noun to count noun grammatical? How about the other direction, of which I'm having a hard time producing an example?

> **Related Questions**
>   [Explanation for “emails”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2425/explanation-for-emails)
>   [Is it wrong to use the word "codes" in a programming context?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20455/is-it-wrong-to-use-the-word-codes-in-a-programming-context)

Comment: There are no "rules". Someone somewhere starts saying something, and it either catches on or it doesn't. See [When does a mistake become standard usage?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9314/), [Descriptivism and widespread misspelling](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3723/), [When does a word become a 'word'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15099/), [Regulatory bodies and authoritative dictionaries for English](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/462/).

Comment: In the case of 'codes' to mean algorithms/libraries I think it's older than the singular use of source code. At least in academic use

Comment: I have no idea who "the M&S community" are, but unquestionably the EL&U community does *not* accept the pluralisation of "codes" as per OP's example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Was there a vote I wasn't aware of?

Comment: @Kosmonaut: On the linked question it seems to me only one answer says that "codes" is acceptable, and that answer has 5 votes. All other answers (with 74 upvotes in total) seem to me to be saying this usage is incorrect.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Heh, so there *was* a vote I wasn't aware of.  (Didn't notice that link the first time around :)

Comment: @Kosmonaut: oic - if you didn't notice the link then obviously you'd have thought my comment was at least odd, if not presumptive. Personally I think pedantic criticism of *emails* is misguided, but I stand firm (and as indicated, not alone) against pluralising *codes* to mean multiple instances of program code.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I actually more or less agree with you on *codes*, in that I don't think it has anything approaching a critical mass of use or acceptability.  I would see the use of *codes* in this fashion as the error of a non-native speaker.

Comment: What is 'M&S'?  Modelling and Simulation?  Marks and Spencer?

Comment: M&S must be modeling and simulation, re-read the full sentence.

Comment: One word has gone the full circle: the noun [cannon](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4568/cannon-as-plural)  (as in artillery) went from a count noun (*two cannons*) to a mass noun (*two pieces of cannon*) to a noun with uninflected plural (*two cannon*) and back to a regular count noun (*two cannons*).

Answer (score 1):

Depending from the context, *codes* is a used word. Looking at the *Corpus of Contemporary American English*, I can find the following sentences.

> In Congress, it presents itself in massive legislation, acts and **codes** thousands of pages long and so monstrously overcomplicated that no human being possibly can read through them - much less understand them or apply them justly to a people who increasingly feel like they no longer are being asked, but rather told.

> After the job was completed, an inspector visited and described a scenario in which a child might climb the spindles as if they were a ladder and tumble to the ground. Lesson Learned: Read **codes** carefully—meeting them is the homeowner's responsibility, and just because a plan is approved, it doesn't mean it meets code.

> Using C-based programming **codes**, the DM-225i series converts motion commands directly to motor currents. The driver includes circuitry required for I/O, communications, and encoder feedback as well as C/C++ motion-control library functions, designed to operate in real time or as a stand-alone configuration, DM-225i can be used in conjunction with a control IBM PC or compatible or as a runtime system without a PC.

Comment: The first two are perfectly reasonable uses of the codes, and an example citing 'codes and ciphers' would be fine too.  Using 'codes' to refer to programs is a ghastly neologism (it seems to have become prevalent in the last couple of years - but that probably means I wasn't paying attention to the right (wrong?) places previously.  I would serious object to the last paragraph as 'good English' for the misuse of 'codes'.